# I don't get the permission prompt to allow permission in Android

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am creating an app, but in order to make it work, I need to have *READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE*.

So I have these two variables:

```java
    String[] request_permission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    boolean isGranted = false;
```

And in the onCreate I call:

```java
 requestPermission();
```

The method is this:

```java
    private void requestPermission(){
      if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,request_permission[0])== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
          isGranted = true;
      }else {
          if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
          }else {
              resultLauncher.launch(request_permission[0]);
          }
      }
    }
```

And the resultLauncher is this:

```java
    ActivityResultLauncher<String> resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), result -> {
       if (result){
           isGranted = true;
           Toast.makeText(this, "granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }else {
           isGranted = false;
           Toast.makeText(this, "notGranted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           sendToSettingsDialog();
       }
    });
```

And I have declared this in the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

So I want to get a prompt to allow permission, but I don't. How can I do it it?

Comment: Not on an Android 13 device.

Comment: Thank for you answer but my phone is updated to android 13

Comment: Then you do not need to ask for those permissions was the message.

Comment: you mean to say that i have the permission  by default in android 13?

Comment: You will know as you already did some read and write test i suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Android 13, the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission has been split into more specific permissions to access different types of files. To request permission to read media files like images, videos, and audio files, you need to request the following permissions:

READ_MEDIA_IMAGES: Allows an app to read media files stored in the image collections of the user's device.
READ_MEDIA_VIDEO: Allows an app to read media files stored in the video collections of the user's device.
READ_MEDIA_AUDIO: Allows an app to read media files stored in the audio collections of the user's device.
To request these permissions, you can follow these steps:

Add the following permissions to your app's AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
```

Declare an array of strings to hold the permissions you want to request:

```
String[] permissions = new String[] {
        Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES,
        Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO,
        Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO
};
```

Check whether the permissions are already granted or not:

```
boolean areAllPermissionsGranted = true;
for (String permission : permissions) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        areAllPermissionsGranted = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (areAllPermissionsGranted) {
    // Permissions are already granted
} else {
    // Permissions are not granted, request the permissions
}
```

If the permissions are not already granted, request the permissions using the ActivityResultLauncher:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> requestPermissionLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(), permissions -> {
            boolean allPermissionsGranted = true;
            for (String permission : permissions.keySet()) {
                if (!permissions.get(permission)) {
                    allPermissionsGranted = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (allPermissionsGranted) {
                // Permissions are granted
            } else {
                // Permissions are denied
            }
        });

requestPermissionLauncher.launch(permissions);
```

Note that in Android 11 and later, you can use the RequestMultiplePermissions contract to request multiple permissions at once, instead of calling the ActivityResultLauncher for each permission separately.

Finally, if the user denies any of the permissions, you can show a dialog explaining why you need the permissions and direct the user to the app's settings to grant the permissions manually.

```
private void showPermissionDeniedDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Permission Denied")
            .setMessage("You have denied one or more of the required permissions. " +
                    "Please grant the permissions in the app settings.")
            .setPositiveButton("Settings", (dialog, which) -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                intent.setData(uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();
}
```

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions

Comment: Android 11? or Android 13 rather ???

Comment: fixed from 11 to 13